# MongoDB (Mongoose) join query with pagination

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have two mongoDB Models

```
var CompanySchema = new Schema({
    company_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    })
    application.accountDB.model('companies', CompanySchema)

var UserSchema = new Schema({
        customer_email: {
        type: String,
        required: false
       },
        company_id: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        ref: 'companies'
       }
    application.accountDB.model('users', UserSchema)
```

I am trying to paginate over companies and also to get email from the users table, But the below query is resulting in paginating over users and populating companies, I want the other way around.

```
 users.find({},{limit:10, page:0 },{populate : [{path:"company",model : application.accountDB.model('companies')}]})
```

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation it sounds like `Companies` is the main collection that you want to focus on, with the ability to view information about `Users` who are associated with that Company?

Based on that use-case, the best approach here would be to operate on the `Companies` schema and then join the `Users` collection after you've paginated the `Companies`.

Also, MongoDB [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) is perfect for this type of query, which I would recommend using. The example I've provided uses Mongo Aggregation to retrieve a paginated list of `Companies` with their associated `Users`.

```
const paginatedCompanies = await Companies.aggregate([
    { $match: { ... } },   // Use this to filter the companies if required
    { $sort: { "<field>": 1 } },   // Replace <field> with the name of whatever field you want to sort on
    { $skip: <skip> },   // Replace <skip> with the number of records you want to skip over 
    { $limit: <limit> },   // Replace <limit> with the page size you want
    { $lookup: {
        from: "Users",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "company_id",
        as: "users"
    } }
]);
```

Which should output something like this:

```
[
    {
        _id: "companyId",
        company_name: "Company Name",
        users: [
            {
                _id: "userId",
                customer_email: "email",
                company_id: "companyId"
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```